# jQuery auto update position of animated div

Tags: jquery, animation, position

hi i want Create script in jquery which will be auto update position of animated div all the time

i have already this but this is not updating all the time

my code at this moment

```
function start(){
    var p = $( "#box" );
    var position = p.position();
    $( "#box" ).text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried a jQuery like :

```
$( "##box" ).click(function() {
$( "#imgsrc" ).animate({
opacity: 0.25,
left: "+=50",
height: "toggle"
}, 5000, function() {
// Animation complete.
});
});
```

Change #imgsrc with your image source.

Comment: look at this http://pastebin.com/XssfKGT2  i want get position of my animated div. now i get it but this is not updating all the time

Answer (score 0):

you will get the position of div after animating

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/L2deyz30/2/)

```
function pos() {
    position = $("#box").position();
    $("#box").text("left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top);
}
pos()

$('#animate').on('click', function () {
    $("#box").animate({
        left: 40
    }, function () {
        pos()
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks :) but can i get postition all the time. when div is moving ?